# Scope of global temporary table relative to ADO.NET database connection?

Tags: t-sql, session, ado.net, connection, database-connection

SQL Server books online states [the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258255(SQL.80).aspx) about visibility (scope?) of temporary tables:

> **Temporary Tables**
>  You can create local and **global** temporary tables.
>   Local temporary tables are visible
>   only in the current session; **global
>   temporary tables are visible to all
>   sessions**.

I want to understand how the  scope of the **global** temporary table relates to an ADO.NET database connection. Will a global temp table created during an ADO.NET connection persist beyond that connection for future connections to use? What about parallel ADO.NET connections that start and stop together?

I'm not seeing the association between Microsoft's use of the word *session* in SQL context and the word *connection* in ADO.NET context, if they're one in the same or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they are the same, a connection gets a session SPID, the table should be there until it is dropped or you restart the sql server instance

in one window do this

```
create table ##temp ( ID int)
insert ##temp values (1)
```

now from another connection do this

```
select * from ##temp
```

Comment: Am I interpreting correctly to understand that SQL Server might assign the same SPID to more than one ADO.NET connection?

Comment: ... but maybe different SPIDs to each connection in a different situation?

Comment: no SPIDs are unique but they do get reused so if a connection comes in with SPID 61 then drops off and then someone else connects he might get 60, in general SPIDs below 51 and system connects and above 50 are user connections..you can run sp_who2 to see who is connected to your instance